# Gravity forms iframe embed will not let me use Conditional Logic

Tags: iframe, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm trying to embed a Gravity form using the iFrames add-on.

I tested the system with a simple form, and it was fine. Then I made a more complex form, and the form disappeared. Eventually, after turning on and off loads of functions, I discovered that by turning off the conditional logic, I could see the form, so there must be some sort of conflict here.

But the instructions for Gravity Form specifically say that I can use the Conditional Logic with the iframe plug in.

The instructions also say that the line of script will enable the iframe to automatically resize to fit the size of the form. But this is not happening either.

Is their something wrong with Gravity Forms, or is there something wrong with me?

Thanks

Comment: Highly unlikely there is something wrong with Gravity Forms. What's the link to the addon and the page you're doing this on?

Comment: Thanks Andy,

This is the page with the form: http://www.prophlebotomytraining.co.uk/course-application-form/

What I have noticed is that the default script for resizing looks like this: <script src="//love-hairandbeauty.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/gravity-forms-iframe-develop/assets/scripts/gfembed.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

So I wondered if it might be something to do with the url: //love-hairandbeauty, and tried changing it to http://www.love-hairandbeauty. No joy.

I also tried using the iframe in the original love-hairandbeauty website, but had the same result.

Comment: I see the form on the page. I guess I'm not sure I am following what the issue is. Why are you trying to embed the form with an iframe? Why not just drop in the shortcode for the form?

Comment: Thanks for looking. The form shows up because I've disabled the Conditional Logic. If I enable the Conditional Logic, the form disappears. Also, the height of the form is supposed to move up and down with each new page / when new fields appear through conditional formatting. The only way I've managed to fit the form is to manually adjust the iFrame height.

Comment: Also, I've got to use an iFrame because the form is being hosted in a site outside of the original site, a sister site to the original. This is apparently exactly what the Gravity Forms iFrame plug in is designed for (https://github.com/bradyvercher/gravity-forms-iframe - it even mentions the height of the form changing with conditional logic, so I know that should be able to work).